# Setting up a restricted user group in MODX

Tags: authorization, acl, modx

I am working with a lot of MODX since 2010. From time to time i coudl need another user group with restricted permissions. Like "Can edit content, but not change settings". So the user can't break anything which is relevant for die CMS itself.

I added users, placed them into roles and groups, but somehow it never works the way I expect it to work. A **role** is not a "role" but a level of authority. A **group** is just a link to a set of permissions, which is already setup as a ruleset. Still, if I create and setup the group "content editor", I never get it running as expected.

Is there a **guide** (or even an **extra**?) to setup restricted user account without breaking ones brain?

Comment: I would advice you to join the MODX community Slack channel from modx.org. Permissions and ACLs are complicated and without a very defined question/outline, is impossible to answer properly.

Comment: As slack is a closed system, I would not ask anything there. Slack answers are lost knowledge for the public. Maybe this is why I still have to ask instead of finding the answer on google :)

Comment: I am well aware of that. The problem with your question is that it is too open ended. It can be solved in many, many different ways, and the solution depends on various details not provided here. This question would then be closed off as too broad, as it is not concrete enough to be answered to a satisfactory degree as is. That was why I suggested deleting it and asking for help on Slack instead.

Comment: Hm. I'd expect that people have solved this before and they have solved it in a similar way. So why not describe that way that works and improve it right here?

Comment: Then you need to ask a more specific question. What permissions should the user have, and what should it not have? Change settings? Does that mean only the system settings? Should they have access to elements? User editing? You also need to specify what roles and groups you have selected and elaborate in details what you mean that it never works the way you expect. StackOverflow require a specific and concrete problem. You are asking for a guide. See the first point in the list here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You're right, I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a basic tutorial available in the official documentation: https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/security/security-tutorials/giving-a-user-manager-access

My personal recommendation would be to ignore roles altogether. Whenever you need to enter a role (when adding a policy to a user group, or when adding a user group to a user) just pick "Super User - 0". They're an added complexity to allow, essentially, different permissions within the same user group, that 99% of the people don't need.

The primary thing to do is to create a policy, based on the "Administrator" policy set, that contains the permissions you want the user to have in the manager. Those would include the relevant resource/document permissions, but not `settings`, for example.

Then you add that policy to the user group of your choice as a "mgr" context policy.

The usergroup will also need context permission to be able of interacting with specific contexts. So on the contexts tab in permissions, add the different contexts you want, with the contexts policy.

As @optimuscrime commented, ACLs can be a little complicated, but that's the general approach.